# Info window on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, infowindow

I am trying to implement in my code something like an info window , but not exactly. I found a very nice tutorial here , [Info Window for iOS](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/showing-a-popup-window-in-ios-class-for-download/) , but what i want to do is when i press on my button , the space under it to expand and show my various options.

I mean i dont want another window to open , but something like a space under the button expanding , revealing stuff. Maybe you have seen this in applications with buttons with a `+` next to them , to reveal more info , and then with a `-` to hide it.

How exactly is this called on iOS and is there a tutorial you are aware of about it?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking for. If you could post a sketch or two of the UI you're trying to achieve, you might get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good for you to look into UIView animation blocks.  These will be useful in the future as well.  This tutorial doesn't do the exact thing you are looking for because it is fairly specific, but this will tell you how to use animation blocks, and you should be able to turn that into what you are looking for.  It is also a good thing to know.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a popup menu, which isn't really provided in iOS.  But you can look at third-party controls such as this one:

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/qbpopupmenu

Comment: not really but thanks for the answer. I dont want it to look like a popup with more buttons. I want to make the view longer under it. Like theres something hidden under the button and then is revealed. It could be text buttons pics etc. :)